# Allow HTML text in Radgrid template column

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

```html
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lblCompanyName" runat="server" 
      ToolTip='<%# CheckDbNull.ToStr(Eval("Name")) %>' 
      Text='<%# CheckDbNull.ToStr(Eval("Name")) %>'>
   </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I have some data in HTML formatted like `<abc>`, `<Name>`, etc., but it will render as HTML and it is not displayed.

How do I display HTML text in grid columns? I am using `Telerik:RadGrid` and template column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `Server.HTMLEncode` for displaying `<` and `>` sign.

Follows

```
   Text='  <%# Server.HTMLEncode(CheckDbNull.ToStr(Eval("Name"))) %>'
```

It changes as following

- The less-than character (<) is converted to &lt ;.
- The greater-than character (>) is converted to &gt ;.
- The ampersand character (&) is converted to &amp ;.
- The double-quote character (") is converted to &quot ;.
- Any ASCII code character whose code is greater-than or equal to 0x80 is converted to &#< number>, where number is the ASCII character value.
  [MSDN says Server.HTMLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347.aspx)

Details are below
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: thanks bro. .it's working but with this solution i have got another problem. When i export grid data into pdf, excel format, html text is not displayed. when i remove Server.HtmlEncode then it will not display in grid but it will display in pdf , excel format